# How do we let users know that they can add their code, even if it doesn't work?

Tags: discussion

I'm just curious, does Stack Overflow tell a user anywhere on the Ask a Question screen that they *should* include their broken code?

For example: [How to validate a cell value in excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46001244/how-to-validate-a-cell-value-in-excel-vba/46004808)

The user posted his question and was quickly down-voted. In the comments he said:

*"Hey Scott I'm new at this. You want me to put code even if it is totally useless? At least Moacir gave something to work on. So I'll put what I have come through"*

He then proceeded to post a good snippet of code that was really close to what he wanted, but sadly he had already received 4 down-votes and wasn't getting much attention.

While I'm sure Stack Overflow already does this, I don't see it when creating a question - I think it could be useful somewhere like on here:

[image]

Comment: "Share your research" is congruent with "share your code", although many may *not* be able to see or agree with the direct correlation...I don't doubt that's the intent.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noeffort http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch

Comment: So wait. We have to tell coders seeking code help that.... They need to show us the code? There is hand holding.... And then there is hand holding.

Comment: @Patrice, But, if we can significantly reduce the number of bad questions (e.g. debugging questions without a MCVE, or even the start of having code) by just adding a little bit of additional text to the ask-a-question page, then let's do it.

Comment: @Will Wow, that's pretty nifty. Bookmarked.

Comment: Something must be off because you still have to request this multiple times a day. I tend to think that people approach this as starting up a dialogue where "experts" are going to request things from them rather than them taking the responsibility to provide everything from the get-go. So yeah, I think you're right to want to add more explicit guidance.

Comment: @Patrice: Automated hand-holding shouldn't bother anyone. It's when it has to be *manual* — as it is now! — that it's a problem.