# Automatically discouraging new users from posting code in comments

Tags: discussion, feature-request, asking-questions

I'm sure we've all seen this:

- user posts question with no code
- someone asks them to post their code
- they post it in a comment

At that point, one of 3 things happens:

- someone <sup><sub>(more patient than me)</sub></sup> kindly edits it into their question and flags the comment as unnecessary
- someone comments telling them to edit their code into their question
- nobody cares enough and the question gets closed or ignored

Note that I've purposefully omitted the option "user edits their code into their own question" for the simple reason in that 90% of the cases, that doesn't happen.

This tells me that something, somewhere, is broken. And I think it's the "How to Ask" box on the "Ask a Question" page:

[image]

Do you see what's missing? No? I'll give you a wee hint: it doesn't say *anything* about **including your code**.

Yes, "Share your research" is pretty self-explanatory - if you're a native English speaker. Yes, the "how to ask" help page is a click away. But let's be honest, we aren't dealing with the cream of the crop here, as it were; we're dealing with the drive-by askers, and a simple wording change/addition to that little cream box could possibly make a world of difference for them (and us).

(I assume the new question wizard avoids this problem entirely, but until or unless that becomes the default, this little suggestion could be very useful).

---

Something that's a bit more work, but would also probably help: when a user is considered a "new contributor" and starts writing a comment **on their own question**, give them a little JS popup informing them that if they are posting their code, they should rather consider editing it into their question.

Comment: Isn't one problem that the comment box accepts new line characters (Shift+Enter or cut'n'pasted) but then silently eats them. Newbies commenting with new lines is probably the biggest "This is code" red flag.

Comment: yes, it would be better to block pastes with newlines, which means that it is 1) code, 2) data, and should be in the question rather than in comments.

Comment: And it doesn't help that the `edit` link is well obfuscated. Even if new users wouldn't easily overlook it; this thing does not convey much purpose. It should be labelled "edit / add new details" and be visually competetive with "add comment" at least.

Comment: I know it isn't a total solution, but one thing that I frequently do when initially *asking* for the code is to say something like `Please [edit] your question...`  The advantage is it gives them a hard link that they see in your comment which links them directly to editing, counteracting the issue @mario pointed out.

Comment: I'd rather we discourage seasoned veterans from posting _answers_ in comments. Far more harmful.

Comment: @anonymous2 - I do the same thing, and I've found that it has roughly the same success rate as not putting the link there.

Comment: @Comintern for those users who aren't following directions anyhow... will adding more guidance help?  I don't know.  It might, but then again it might not.  I'm not objecting to Ian's ideas; if they're not hard to implement, there's nothing wrong with them.  I'm just wondering if it'll actually help. Just food for thought.  :)

Comment: `when a user is considered a "new contributor" and starts writing a comment on their own question` Yes, and besides the mention about code also one about using `@` to "ping" a specific comment author. Because such a comment is usually replying to a request and that person needs to see there's been a reply.

Comment: Related: my feature request to [Raise / Remove reputation limit for showing “Do not upload code screenshots” message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367875/5389131) that currently is displayed in the image upload dialog for hardly anyone. And if it is displayed, it's barely noticeable.

Comment: SO can't save these people from themselves. It takes a minimum of effort to look at your own comment after posting and then activate a minimum of one's brain: oops, this is an unreadable mess, nobody can read this, how do I do this proper.

Comment: About the last point: "posting their code" can be edited to "answering a clarification request" or "adding  information to the question"

Comment: @Lundin They don't need to read the code they're posting, the poor work drones (**we**) have to, but we don't have a brain and we will do everything for the OP, and write *aaaaall* the code for them (for free of course)

Comment: @Lundin that's what comments and user moderation permissions are for is to help new users understand how to use the system correctly very much the community helping the community. SO is supposed to be helping the developer community, i would say that is one of the Jobs of community moderators, not the diamond mods so the people like Me and You where we have the ability to edit / moderate questions

Comment: ironically this question shouldn't be here. it belongs to ux stackexchange.

Comment: Such a good question, and there's  many use cases of the comments and answer box that are frequently mistaken. It's frustrating. I'm not even sure red flashing lights and electric keyboard shocks will help. Some people treat the site like a forum and do not follow the flow. There's many assumptions made when using the internet that is based on previous experience. I now have a canned comment: *"Stack Overflow is not a forum. Answers boxes are for solutions only. See how to [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering)."*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do we let users know that they can add their code, even if it doesn't work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356042/how-do-we-let-users-know-that-they-can-add-their-code-even-if-it-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 5):

> it doesn't say anything about including your code. ... a simple wording change/addition to that little cream box could possibly make a world of difference for them (and us).

Please, no. Crafting an MCVE, where applicable, is pretty much always useful, but posting a giant wall of code with no attempt to debug is not. If we tell users to post "your code", nine times out of ten what we will get (from users who otherwise would've omitted code that was vital to the question) is going to be the latter.

Meanwhile, it'll harm the quality of questions that *don't* require code to be clear and useful. Not every question benefits from including code, but if we add an instruction asking for it then capable but unconfident askers will decide to include it anyway in an attempt to conform to the rules.

Users who are capable of grasping what makes a useful question will manage to create one in absence of guidance, and those who don't will frequently fail no matter what guidance they're given. That's life, and I can live with it. I just don't want to damage the output of *competent* new users and drive them away from the site by presenting what is far from universal advice about how to craft a good question as if it is a rule.

Comment: Absolutely agreed. If all you want is somebody to look over your code, go to the Code Review. There is simply no need for this site to be spammed with senseless code that doesn't bring any value to the question (or answer). If somebody is asking in comments for code, it's because they think it will help them, or others, answer the question. NOT necessarily because the code is not there and should have been. My highest voted answer is to a question that didn't have, or need, any code pasted in whatsoever.

Answer (score -19):

I don't know how difficult this would be to implement, or if it's been discussed before, but what about changing the way that the New Post form is laid out?  Specifically, create 2 different text boxes, one for text, and one for code.  This would also have the benefit of making code entry simpler (no needing to correct spacing repeatedly), it could make it simpler to collapse long code, and there could be a specific layout format for code.  You could still allow inline code in the text area, for inline reference to objects, variables, etc, but overall the code would go in a different box.  Most questions do (or should) have code, but for those few that validly don't there could be a "No Code" checkbox, button, etc to allow a question to be posted without code.

What does everyone think?

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378057/2846923

Comment: If you're "correct spacing repeatedly" then you're doing it wrong. From [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help): "You can also select text and press CTRL+K to toggle indenting as code." or "Instead of using indentation, you can also create code blocks by using “code fences”, consisting of three or more backticks or tildes"

Comment: Even if there's a separate box to enter code, guidance would still be necessary (otherwise how can they know what the box is used for?), and if there's help then the UI change would be unnecessary.

Comment: plus in my posts I often explain/describe something, followed by some code, then explain something... what you're proposing encourages code dumps.

Comment: @user202729: There would be help inasmuch as there would be a title (ie-Enter Code), but separating the entries would implicitly require both text AND code, as opposed to now where there is just a single box for both.  Currently there's a request for code, but not a demand exactly.  I was also picturing the boxes being on two different pages (submit text, Next button, submit code).

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre:. True, I hadn't thought of that...maybe the solution there is to have this "wizard" question entry be based on reputation level.  So until the reach rep of say 10-15 (random number choice), they would get the wizard, then they would start to get the current approach.  Kind of a moot argument anyways given how many down votes this already has.  

Comment: @user202720: Also, with the code spacing, I have to do this when I copy-paste code, as depending on what indentation my code has and where I start the selection, there may not be any indentation to the code at first.